# Como calcular a quantidade de linhas em um texto numa <p> ou <div> com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

A minha pergunta não está relacionada restritamente com a quantidade de quebras de linha `<br>` ou com uso de `\n` em tags `<pre>`. O que eu quero saber é a quantidade de linhas que um texto apresenta em uma tag HTML como `<p>` ou `<div>`. Imagine que eu tenha o seguinte corpo (`body`) HTML e `script` JS:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let quant = 3; /*Qual o comando a ser inserido aqui?*/
  let addS = "";
  if (quant > 1) {
    addS = "s";
  }
  alert("Há " + quant + " linha" + addS + " no texto!");
});
```

```html
<input type=button value="Quantas linhas possui o texto abaixo?">
<p style="width: 300px">
  <!--Texto genérico abaixo -->
  Lorem ipsum porta consectetur sollicitudin arcu sodales elit nunc, morbi varius aliquam ultricies augue cras dui fringilla, auctor amet ac mattis praesent suspendisse nunc. arcu mi faucibus aliquam erat sagittis pharetra egestas, scelerisque nostra ligula
  aliquam rhoncus placerat nec, mattis at nullam morbi sapien magna. curae imperdiet senectus accumsan hendrerit pretium accumsan lorem curae fringilla, imperdiet sapien turpis curabitur dictum urna interdum leo inceptos tellus, fusce malesuada quisque
  venenatis platea neque euismod porta. fames ut donec hendrerit primis placerat integer amet sollicitudin interdum nisl, etiam posuere dictum dui semper netus orci arcu ad erat, vehicula nisl netus conubia arcu neque felis augue nec.
</p>
```

Já criado o `addEventListener` no JS, a questão é o comando que identifica a quantidade de linhas que o texto tem no elemento `<p>` (mas não somente a quantidade de tags `<br>` ou de `\n`, e sim as quebras "naturais").

Comment: Ficou um pouco confuso a que você se refere quando diz quebras de linhas "naturais". Você diz em relação a quando o próprio navegador divide o texto, por exemplo para caber tudo na tela? Ou então se refere ao "enter" quando alguém digita algo? No caso do exemplo do Lorem ipsum que colocou, ele teria quantas quebras de linhas?

Comment: Primeira resposta: Sim, as quebras "naturais" que eu citei são as que o próprio navegador divide. Segunda resposta: Não. No caso do texto Lorem ipsum que coloquei de exemplo e considerando a quantidade de "enter", ele teria 0 quebras de linhas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Cálculo de quantidade de linhas

É possível calcular quantas linhas um elemento possui dividindo o seu [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) pelo seu [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) e arredondando para cima (se o resultado for `3.1` linhas, na verdade o elemento precisa de `4` linhas para ser exibido).

- `scrollHeight` é uma medida da altura do conteúdo do elemento, incluindo o conteúdo não visível na tela devido ao *overflow*.
- `line-height` é uma propriedade que define a altura de uma caixa de linha, ou seja, a altura do texto da linha incluindo o espaçamento entre as linhas.

### Algoritmo para o cálculo

Para obter o `scrollHeight`, basta acessar a propriedade diretamente o elemento HTML `elemento.scrollHeight`.

Para o `line-height` temos um pouco mais de complexidade:

1. `line-height` é um valor CSS, calculado pelo navegador. Utilizamos enntão [`window.getComputedStyle(elemento)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) para obter todos os valores de estilo calculados do elemento em questão.
2. Como a função acima retorna uma lista de valores de propriedades diferentes, buscamos pelo valor desejado com [`listaDeValoresCalculados.getPropertyValue('line-height')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue).
3. No CSS, o `line-height` pode possuir valores como `inherit`, `normal`, `15px`, `3rem` etc. Ao obter o valor calculado com a função acima, podemos receber ou `normal` ou o valor em `px`.
4. Convertemos o valor calculado para inteiro com [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

   4.1. Se o valor era `15px`, agora será `15`, tudo certo.

   4.2. Se o valor era `normal`, agora será `NaN`. Caso seja `NaN`, precisamos calcular o `line-height` de outra maneira.

   - 4.2.1. Clonamos o elemento com [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) para termos um elemento com todas as propriedades de estilo iguais.
   - 4.2.2. Pegamos a altura do elemento com [`offSetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) quando ele tem uma única linha (`<br>`) e quando tem duas linhas (`<br><br>`).
   - 4.2.3. Subtraímos a altura de duas linhas pela de uma linha (`alturaDuasLinhas - alturaUmaLinha`), esse é o `line-height` que usaremos. Isso é necessário pois a altura de uma única linha inclui o *padding*, por exemplo, podendo valer `40` quando na verdade o `line-height` é de `15px`, e então a altura de duas linhas valeria `55`, e `55 - 40 = 15`.

Agora já temos os valores de `scrollHeight` e `line-height`. Fazemos a divisão e arredondamos para cima: `Math.ceil(scrollHeight / lineHeight)`.

### Exemplo

No exemplo abaixo aplico o algoritmo descrito acima. Além disso, resolvi obter o `lineHeight` apenas uma vez, quando a página carregar com [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), pois como é um processo mais complexo, faço ele apenas uma vez.

Caso seu CSS mude dinamicamente, pode ser que o `line-height` mude, por exemplo. Nesse caso, adapte o código para suas necessidades.

```js
let lineHeightParagrafo;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  lineHeightParagrafo = getLineHeight(document.querySelector("p"))
});

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const paragrafo = document.querySelector("p");
  const quant = Math.ceil(paragrafo.scrollHeight / lineHeightParagrafo);
  let addS = "";
  if (quant > 1) {
    addS = "s";
  }
  alert("Há " + quant + " linha" + addS + " no texto!");
});

function getLineHeight(elemento) {
  const estiloComputado = window.getComputedStyle(elemento);
  /* A propriedade pode ter valor 'normal' ou em 'px',
     mesmo que você tenha atribuído em 'rem' */
  const stringLineHeight = estiloComputado.getPropertyValue('line-height');
  let lineHeight = parseInt(stringLineHeight, 10);

  /* Caso o valor seja 'normal', então lineHeight não será um número,
     então criamos um elemento novo para calcular o lineHeight */
  if (isNaN(lineHeight)) {
    /* <br> fará com que o clone tenha apenas uma linha,
      para descobrir o lineHeight é necessário calcular a
      diferença de tamanho entre duas linhas, porque
      a existência de padding influenciará o retorno de offSetHeight */
    const clone = elemento.cloneNode();
    clone.innerHTML = '<br>';
    elemento.appendChild(clone);
    const alturaComUmaLinha = clone.offsetHeight;

    clone.innerHTML = '<br><br>';
    const alturaComDuasLinhas = clone.offsetHeight;
    elemento.removeChild(clone);

    lineHeight = alturaComDuasLinhas - alturaComUmaLinha;
  }

  return lineHeight;
}
```

```html
<input type=button value="Quantas linhas possui o texto abaixo?">
<p style="width: 300px">
  <!--Texto genérico abaixo -->
  Lorem ipsum porta consectetur sollicitudin arcu sodales elit nunc, morbi varius aliquam ultricies augue cras dui fringilla, auctor amet ac mattis praesent suspendisse nunc. arcu mi faucibus aliquam erat sagittis pharetra egestas, scelerisque nostra ligula
  aliquam rhoncus placerat nec, mattis at nullam morbi sapien magna. curae imperdiet senectus accumsan hendrerit pretium accumsan lorem curae fringilla, imperdiet sapien turpis curabitur dictum urna interdum leo inceptos tellus, fusce malesuada quisque
  venenatis platea neque euismod porta. fames ut donec hendrerit primis placerat integer amet sollicitudin interdum nisl, etiam posuere dictum dui semper netus orci arcu ad erat, vehicula nisl netus conubia arcu neque felis augue neca.
</p>
```

---

O algoritmo para obter o `line-height` em caso de `normal` foi adaptado [de uma resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18430767/8839059).

Comment: Muito bom, coloquei width: 100% e ao redimensionar o navegador respondeu certinho!

Comment: Valeu! Faço uso de um código similar para criar uma `<textarea>` que aumenta a quantidade de linhas conforme digita :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, Rafael. Até pensei em aplicar um modelo baseado em dividir a altura do elemento pela altura da linha no código, mas estava em dúvida quanto a existência de um comando já existente na linguagem JS que contabiliza linhas (pelo jeito, é isso mesmo hehe). Vlw!